Python files missing from Azure Function
I'm trying to deploy a simple Python function through the Azure CLI within a Consumption hosting plan, using Linux. I'm using a Free Trial subscription.
The code follows the following directory structure:
blob-trigger-app
├── LICENSE
├── README.md
├── blob-trigger
│   └── __init__.py
├── host.json
└── requirements.txt

Since the function uses the v2 programming model, function.json file is not present inside the blob-trigger subdirectory.
I have my file zipped with the following structure after zipping:
$ unzip -l blob-trigger-app.zip

unzip -l blob-trigger-app.zip
Archive:  blob-trigger-app.zip
  Length      Date    Time    Name
---------  ---------- -----   ----
    11357  11-01-2024 13:32   LICENSE
       39  11-01-2024 13:32   README.md
        0  11-02-2024 09:23   blob-trigger/
     1654  11-02-2024 09:23   blob-trigger/__init__.py
       43  11-01-2024 16:39   host.json
      100  11-02-2024 09:09   requirements.txt
---------                     -------
    13193                     6 files

After some struggles I finally got this command to work:
functionapp deployment source config-zip \
    --resource-group some-group \
    --name some-app \
    --src ./blob-trigger-app.zip

The app doesn't seem to be running, so I've looked in the Functions > App files in Azure Portal, and I can see a list of files including all from the root directory, but not the blob-trigger subdirectory:

Can there be any particular reasons for why the python directory is not there? Or is it there but for some reason it's simply not being displayed? Is there to debug is further?
The app code is quite trivial:
@app.blob_trigger(
    arg_name="blob", 
    path="in-csv/{name}",
    connection="AzureWebJobsStorage"
)
def main(blob: func.InputStream):
    logging.info('######')
    print(">>>>>>")
    logging.info(f"Name: {blob.name}, Size: {blob.length}")

The app seems to be running, as there are some logs under Log Stream, but they're not related to Python code:
2024-11-05T13:10:33Z   [Verbose]   Initiating background SyncTriggers operation
2024-11-05T13:10:33Z   [Information]   Loading functions metadata
2024-11-05T13:10:33Z   [Information]   Reading functions metadata (Custom)
2024-11-05T13:10:33Z   [Information]   0 functions found (Custom)
2024-11-05T13:10:33Z   [Information]   0 functions loaded
2024-11-05T13:10:33Z   [Information]   HttpOptions
{
  "DynamicThrottlesEnabled": false,
  "EnableChunkedRequestBinding": false,
  "MaxConcurrentRequests": -1,
  "MaxOutstandingRequests": -1,
  "RoutePrefix": "api"
}
2024-11-05T13:10:33Z   [Information]   ConcurrencyOptions
{
  "DynamicConcurrencyEnabled": false,
  "MaximumFunctionConcurrency": 500,
  "CPUThreshold": 0.8,
  "SnapshotPersistenceEnabled": true
}
2024-11-05T13:10:33Z   [Information]   Loading functions metadata
2024-11-05T13:10:33Z   [Information]   Reading functions metadata (Custom)
2024-11-05T13:10:33Z   [Information]   0 functions found (Custom)
2024-11-05T13:10:33Z   [Information]   0 functions loaded
...


Have you got any error in the Azure function app?

Can you share your code?

@DasariKamali Added some more info. I'm not sure the app code is useful, as it doesn't seem to be loaded at all.

Can you add the local.settings.json file path in the above project structure?

Can you try the project structure like this blob-trigger-app
├── LICENSE
├── README.md
├── local.settings.json
│──  function_app.py
├── host.json
└── requirements.txt.

As mentioned in this MS DOC, there is no need to create a separate file inside the blob trigger function. You can define the code for all functions within the function application in a single file, function_app.py.
Project structure :

function_app.py :
import azure.functions as func  
import logging

app = func.FunctionApp()
@app.blob_trigger(  
arg_name="blob",  
path="in-csv/{name}",  
connection="AzureWebJobsStorage"  
)  

def main(blob: func.InputStream):  
logging.info('######')  
print(">>>>>>")  
logging.info(f"Name: {blob.name}, Size: {blob.length}")

local.settings.json :
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "<storageConnecString>",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "python",
    "defaultresourcegrou85e7_STORAGE": "<storageConnecString>"
  }
}

Output :
The blob trigger function ran successfully as shown below.

I used the below PowerShell command to zip the blob_trigger function project.
Compress-Archive -Path * -DestinationPath blob_trigger_app.zip -Force

After logging in to my Azure account using the az login command, I tried the following command to perform the zip deployment for the Blob Trigger Function.
az functionapp deployment source config-zip -g <ResourceGroupName> -n <FunctionAppName> --src "path-t0-project\blob_trigger_app\blob_trigger_app.zip"

I got the Blob Trigger function in the Azure Function App after a successful ZIP deployment.

Add the following connection to the Environment variables section under App settings in the Azure Function app.
"defaultresourcegrou85e7_STORAGE": "<storageConnecString>"


Azure Function App Invocations :
The blob trigger function ran successfully in the Azure function app.

